# Upgrade modules

Tags: 8, migrations, composer

I am going from Drupal 7.6 to 8.6 using the migration UI (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/upgrade/upgrade-using-drush). When I get to /upgrade/review it lists out the modules that need upgrading.

The issue that, in a new blank website of Drupal 8, I have Drupal 8 modules (like views_slideshow via https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow/releases/8.x-4.6) installed and enabled. However, on the review page, it still shows *Not upgraded*. My path for the module is modules/contrib. I even tried to move this to the *modules* directory with no avail. I have tried upgraded multiple modules but they are all said not to be upgraded. Any direction would be helpful!

Comment: Views Slideshow doesn't have a 7 -> 8 upgrade path, maybe it's just informing you that the module wasn't upgraded

Comment: May you elaborate a bit more about module's upgrade path. Are there any modules that have upgrade paths? If so how would I be able to find out?

Comment: Yes, modules that implement upgrade paths have them Usually it's listed on the module's page or readme (it's on both for views slideshow, for example)

Comment: Thanks that makes way more sense now! May you answer it under my question so I may give you credit.